# Is it possible to access packaged/bundled file from c++ code?

Tags: c++, cmake, package

I'm creating C++ project with CMake. I want to package the default setting written in JSON and access that from within the app, but I couldn't get file...

The code:

```
string filename = "settings.json"
ifstream in(filename, std::ios::in);

string line, jsonString;
while(std::getline(in, line)) {
    jsonString += line + "\n";

    *text = jsonString;
}
```

CMake:

```
add_custom_command(
        TARGET ${EXE_NAME}
        POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/settings.json ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${EXE_NAME}
        )
```

I think the problem probably is in the path however I couldn't solve it.

Comment: So the file `settings.json` is not copied to the build folder after you execute this custom post build command?

Comment: I was confused.. It didn't succeed... Error copying file  `"/Users/***/settings.json" to "/Users/***/cmake-build-debug/***.app/". make[3]: *** [***.app] Error 1 make[3]: *** Deleting file `***.app' make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/***.app.dir/all] Error 2 . make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/***.app.dir/rule] Error 2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use *configure_file* for this:

```
configure_file(settings.json settings.json COPYONLY)
```

This will copy the file again if you change it.